# SubscribeOn does not change the thread pool for the whole chain

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to trigger longer running operation via rest request and WebFlux. The result of a call should just return an info that operation has started. The long running operation I want to run on different scheduler (e.g. Schedulers.single()). To achieve that I used subscribeOn:

```
Mono<RecalculationRequested> recalculateAll() {
  return provider.size()
      .doOnNext(size -> log.info("Size: {}", size))
      .doOnNext(size -> recalculate(size))
      .map(RecalculationRequested::new);
}

private void recalculate(int toRecalculateSize) {
  Mono.just(toRecalculateSize)
      .flatMapMany(this::toPages)
      .flatMap(page -> recalculate(page))
      .reduce(new RecalculationResult(), RecalculationResult::increment)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
      .subscribe(result -> log.info("Result of recalculation - success:{}, failed: {}",
          result.getSuccess(), result.getFailed()));
}

private Mono<RecalculationResult> recalculate(RecalculationPage pageToRecalculate) {
  return provider.findElementsToRecalculate(pageToRecalculate.getPageNumber(), pageToRecalculate.getPageSize())
      .flatMap(this::recalculateSingle)
      .reduce(new RecalculationResult(), RecalculationResult::increment);
}

private Mono<RecalculationResult> recalculateSingle(ElementToRecalculate elementToRecalculate) {
  return recalculationTrigger.recalculate(elementToRecalculate)
      .doOnNext(result -> {
        log.info("Finished recalculation for element: {}", elementToRecalculate);
      })
      .doOnError(error -> {
        log.error("Error during recalculation for element: {}", elementToRecalculate, error);
      });
}
```

From the above I want to call:

```
private void recalculate(int toRecalculateSize)
```

in a different thread. However, it does not run on a single thread pool - it uses a different thread pool. I would expect subscribeOn change it for the whole chain. What should I change and why to execute it in a single thread pool?

Just to mention - method:

```
provider.findElementsToRecalculate(...)
```

uses WebClient to get elements.

Comment: At which point do you observe that it runs on a different thread than expected? If you just want your recalculate method to be async relatively to the main flow, you don't need to do anything. WebClient publishes the response asynchronously and doesn't block any thread.

Comment: I would expect that all inside recalculate method runs on a thread pool single. However, I see it runs on reactor netty pool

Comment: But why is that a problem? You don't need to worry about long IO operations as long as you use WebClient, it won't block any threads.

Comment: I just want to understand thread model there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One caveat of `subscribeOn` is it does what it says: it runs the act of "subscribing" on the provided `Scheduler`. Subscribing flows from bottom to top (the `Subscriber` subscribes to its parent `Publisher`), at runtime.

Usually you see in documentation and presentations that `subscribeOn` affects the whole chain. That is because most operators / sources will not themselves change threads, and by default will start sending `onNext`/`onComplete`/`onError` signals from the thread from which they were subscribed to.

But as soon as one operator switches threads in that top-to-bottom data path, the reach of `subscribeOn` stops there. Typical example is when there is a `publishOn` in the chain.

The source of data in this case is `reactor-netty` and `netty`, which operate on their own threads and thus act as if there was a `publishOn` at the source.

For WebFlux, I'd say favor using `publishOn` in the main chain of operators, or alternatively use `subscribeOn` inside of inner chains, like inside `flatMap`.

Comment: Does it mean that if I have source of data which operates on their own thread (e.g. WebClient or delayElements) there is no sense to add subscribeOn because the consumer in subscribe will use latest thread?

Comment: @Adam that is correct. see https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/13/flight-of-the-flux-3-hopping-threads-and-schedulers for a more in-depth view of the impact of publishOn/subscribeOn

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) , all operators prefixed with doOn , are sometimes referred to as having a “side-effect”. They let you peek inside the sequence’s events without modifying them.

If you want to chain the 'recalculate' step after 'provider.size()' do it with flatMap.